# Android: Error while adding the xml files to another xml

Tags: android, layout-inflater

Error while adding/Inflating the xml files to another xml

I am trying to add the xml files to another xml's but while addidng/inflating i m getting the error.

my main xml is

item_non_highlight.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="10"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/column_big"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
  />

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/column_small"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 />
```

piece of code is here which shows my error

```
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_non_highlight, null);
        LinearLayout column_highlight = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.column_big);
        v = setupHighlightViewTablet(column_highlight);



       private View setupHighlightViewTablet(View parentView) {
       int itemCount = 1;


            LinearLayout columnOdd = (LinearLayout) parentView.
                    findViewById(R.id.social_media_column_one);  // this two layouts belongs to a different xml

            LinearLayout columnEven = (LinearLayout) parentView.
                    findViewById(R.id.social_media_column_two);   //
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.highlight, null);
         if (itemCount % 2 == 0) {
                  columnEven.addView(itemView);
              } else {
                  columnOdd.addView(itemView); // error at this ine
              }
          }
            itemCount++;

    return parentView;

       }
```

error is

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
```

Thanks

Comment: `social_media_column_one` and `social_media_column_two` don't exist under `column_big` how do you expect this to work?

Comment: Ya I know that but Is there any possibility to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Try inflating your layout with false flag as 3rd param:

```
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_non_highlight, null, false);
```

You get exception because by default android tries to add newly inflated view to it's parent (second param) and as you passed there null you get mentioned exception.

See this doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer and I tried it but now i am getting this error   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)